# uninstall SSMS un-configure DSN (ODBC)

Tags: odbc, ssms, dsn

Removing SQL Server Management Studio client, on a running environment with 5 proper configured 32-bits DSN on the ODBC (admin tool), prevented my configured DSN to properly work: they were un.configurable (no chance to click the configure button) and the sub-system working with them was of course running anymore.
Re-installing SSMS client keep the DSN working once again.
I did not find any explanation on this on the web: does somebody knows the why?

Comment: Which version of SSMS were you using?

Comment: SSMS 12 (build 11.0.5058.0)